# Is it valid to use samples drawn from posterior using MCMC as prior distribution in sequational updating?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, posterior

Let's say there are two sets of parameters $x$ and $y$, and two sets of data $a$ and $b$. $x$ only depends on $a$, but $y$ depends on both $a$ and $b$. I first sample from the posterior 
$$P(x \mid a) \propto P(a \mid x) P(x)$$
using MCMC. Now, I need to sample from the posterior
$$P(x, y \mid a, b) \propto P(b \mid x, y, a) P(x \mid a) P(y).$$

The computation is broken into two steps because it is expensive to compute $P(a \mid x)$, but easy to compute $P(b \mid x, y, a)$. In this way the first posterior $P (x \mid a)$ becomes the prior for the second step. Is it valid to sample from $P(b \mid x,y,a)P(y)$ using a 2nd MCMC for each sample of $P(x \mid a)$, so that the final combined sample reflects the final posterior $P(x,y \mid a, b)$? If not, what is a valid way to achieve this?

Comment: Assuming $x$ and $y$ are a priori independent?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: This is a "cut" model, not a regular model.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$ P(x, y \mid a, b) \propto P(b \mid x, y, a) P(x \mid a) P(y) \propto P(b \mid x, y, a)  P(a \mid x) P(x) P(y) $$
the marginal posterior in $x$ satisfies
$$ P(x\mid a, b) = \int P(x, y \mid a, b)\text{d}y \propto \int  P(b \mid x, y, a) \,P(y) \text{d}y \, P(a \mid x) \, P(x) $$
with no reason for the above integral to be independent from $x$.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Can you please elaborate a bit more. If the integral is dependent on $x$, what does that imply? Can you point me to any reference for proper treatment of cut models with MCMC?